# VBA Format Date doesn't work due to Windows regional settings (I think)

Tags: vba, date, format, regional-settings

So I try this:

```
gestern = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1), "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

...and instead of `DD/MM/YYYY` I get `DD.MM.YYYY`.

I think it has to do with the regional settings on my Windows - they are set up for Germany now. There it states the default format for dates is `DD.MM.YYYY`. So I think this is the reason for my issue. But I can't change it back to English, because then some of my other macros are not functioning properly anymore. Furthermore I did not see an option there too add alternative date formats.

Any ideas on how to get the yesterday's date in format `DD/MM/YYYY` without changing the regional settings of Windows? Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you want the date to be displayed as "DD/MM/YYYY"? Does your code return a date that is displayed within a cell in your spreadsheet?

Comment: I want a variable that is supposed to be compared with a column of cells containing dates in format "DD/MM/YYYY" in an If statement. Than I want to take out the rows where the dates are different. Currently the If is constantly returning false, since I cannot convert the variable to "DD/MM/YYYY".

Comment: You can use `gestern = Replace(Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1),"DD/MM/YYYY"), format(now,"/"),"/")`, but there must be a easier way to  do that.

Comment: Ok, there IS a better way to do that, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to escape the `/`character so that it is not seen as a date separator by Format. To escape it, use the `\` character:

```
gestern = Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1),"DD\/MM\/YYYY")
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot!